# Is sessionCreated() from a HttpSessionListener automatically synchronized with request.getSession()?

Tags: java, multithreading, session, servlets, listener

Is `sessionCreated()` method from a `HttpSessionListener` automatically synchronized with `request.getSession()` call? In particular, I would like to know if it is thread safe to set a session attribute in the `sessionCreated()` method and retrieve the attribute with `request.getSession().getAttribute("something")` in a servlet?
For example, is it thread-safe to have

```
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
  se.getSession().setAttribute("something", new Something());
}
```

in a `HttpSessionListener`, and have

```
Something something = (Something) request.getSession().getAttribute("something");
synchronized(something){
  // do anything with this "something" object
}
```

inside of a `doGet()` method of a `HttpServlet?` The point of my concern is that if this `sessionCreated()` method is not automatically synchronized with `requested.getSession()` the value returned by `getAttribute("something")` can be `null`.

Comment: related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158685/is-httpsessionlistener-sessioncreated-guaranteed-to-complete-before-any-other and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802165/is-synchronization-within-an-httpsession-feasible

Answer (score 0):

These two method calls are executed in the same thread, at least in Tomcat. I checked it with printing thread IDs using log4j. Therefore, the combination of the method calls, described above, is thread-safe, at least in Tomcat.

Comment: same for Jetty, btw

Comment: also Spring's `WebUtils.getSessionMutex()` assumes that if an attribute initialized by `sessionCreated()` exists, it's safe to synchronize session access on it.